# Button control takes some time to disable in dialog box

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to do some lengthy operation from my mainthread in dialog box. During that time i want to disable few controls. I used EnableWindow(FALSE) for each control to disable it. But apart from button control all other controls (i.e. slider control, CMFCEditBrowse Control, ComboBox control) are disabling perfectly before the processing. But the button controls are taking more time to disable. They are almost disabling when the operation is going to end. Why the button controls were not disabling as soon as i call EnableWindow(FALSE)? Why it is taking time to disable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the background task totally in another thread, and UI/control changes in another thread. You should use `PostMessage`, if direct call to `EnableWindow` doesn't work. `SetFocus`, for example, doesn't work from a different thread.

Comment: If suppose my UI thread is busy with doing the lengthy operation and messages posted by EnableWindow(false) are waiting in queue yet to be processed, then all controls should not be disabled, right? My question is why button controls alone are not disabling?